# Error in lookahead function

Tags: php, arrays, function, regex-lookarounds

I have this variable data:

```
87||2|#88||3|#209|||#89||1|51#152|||#41||1|#4||1|#3||1|117#20|||#13|53,36|4|#17|7 50|1|#23||1|50014#15|||Condominiale#19||1|Parcheggio condominiale#150|||#24|||86#36|||50032#37|||94`



function caratteristiche1($title) {
  $input = "$title";
  $new_array = preg_match('/(\d+(?=#88||))/', $input);
  print_r($new_array);
}
`
```

I don't understand where is the error. It reports always 1, not the number after

```
#88||...
```

Comment: Please, read about return value of preg_match. Also. `$input = "$title";` - do not do that.

Comment: Also, add your desiring behaviour of your functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Ok but the input is variable, so what i've to write in this case? What about beahaviour? I'm sorry but is the first time that i'm using lookahead function... Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems Pretty Unclear. What you want to achieve over here

Comment: I need just to extract the value after the two pipes. For ex. (...|#88||3....) I need just the number 3.

Comment: And what is `$input` over here

Comment: Instead of `/(\d+(?=#88||))/` use `/\|#88\|\|(\d+?)\b/`

Comment: [Check This](https://regex101.com/r/dE2zC4/1)

Comment: Thank you so much Uchiha. I use: function caratteristiche1($title) {
$input = "$title";
$new_array = preg_match('/\|#88\|\|(\d+?)\b/', $input);
print_r($new_array);
}

Comment: But it always report 1 or 0. Not the right number after two pipes.

Comment: I write this one: is it correct?        function caratteristiche1($title) {
$title = preg_match('/\|#88\|\|(\d+?)\b/', $title);
print_r($title);
}

Comment: Uchica thanks for your Regex example! If i use:       $re = "/\\|#88\\|\\|(\\d+?)\\b/"; 
$str = "87||2|#88||3|#209|||#89||1|51#152|||#41||1|#4||1|#3||1|117#20|||#13|53,36|4|#17|7,50|1|#23||1|50014#15|||Condominiale#19||1|Parcheggio condominiale#150|||#24|||86#36|||50032#37|||94"; 
$subst = ""; 
 
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str); it reports (' '), probably because $str= is always different...   What can i do?

Comment: I can't get you what you want to be an expected output

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape those `||` characters, they have a special meaning in the regular expression: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php.

Comment: I know but i've these in my data... how to explain that what I need is after that 2 pipes?

Comment: Escape the pipes in your regular expression, not in the data!